# What is one of my names?

Tags: riddle, story, steganography

The clues are hidden in the following paragraphs:

> "Xenon knows creation defiantly." Kobold Company is in the business of isolating trace amounts of this element. Creating vials of inert gases literally from thin air is a difficult task. Despite the complexity, however, Kobold Company is a strong leader in the industry, producing hundreds of thousands pounds of the gas per year.
>
> I am an employee of Koblod Company, but not just any employee. I was one of the first four, if you don't count the "office pets" and TV friends shown on the office's most popular show. People call me a strange character. I have taken on many roles whenever I deemed them necessary. Once, I have taken the role of an actuary. Another time, I baked a friend a cake when he was feeling upset. More recently, I devised a free reminder system and launched it to the public. I've been a truther of late, and an informer of water requirements.

I mainly go by two names. What is one?

Comment: "Koblod" - typo or clue?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Would the [[tag:steganography]] tag be appropriate here?

Comment: @Deusovi Yep! I'll add that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're

> Black Hat, from XKCD

Because "Xenon knows creation defiantly."

> Is XKCD, and he was one of the earlier characters.

Also, we can see this by looking...

> ...at the first letters from each sentence in the first paragraph.

He's filled all the roles mentioned, as seen below:

Actuary:

> https://www.xkcd.com/493/

Cake:

> https://xkcd.com/142/

Reminder:

> https://xkcd.com/1207/

Truther:

> https://www.xkcd.com/1717/

Water:

> http://www.xkcd.com/1708/

Comment: I'm counting this one as answered because it has more of the clues. @HughMeyers was right about the one you missed, though. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 4):

Are you ...

> Black Hat?
> first appearance http://xkcd.com/12/ and one of the first regular characters.
>
> Xenon knows creation defiantly = xkcd.
> no idea what Kobold Company refers to.

Comment: In which case, the other name is probably "Classhole".

Comment: For your question about Kobold company, rot13: Ybbx ng gur svefg yrggre bs rnpu fragrapr.